# Javascript game counter pause and unpause

Tags: javascript, counter

I am making a game for my school project, and i have this score counter:

```
function countUp(count)
{
 var div_by = 100,
  speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
  $display = $('.count'),
  run_count = 1,
  int_speed = 24;

var int = setInterval(function() {
if(run_count < div_by){
  $display.text(speed * run_count);
  run_count++;
} else if(parseInt($display.text()) < count) {
  var curr_count = parseInt($display.text()) + 1;
  $display.text(curr_count);
} else {
  clearInterval(int);
}
}, int_speed);
}

countUp(1209);
```

It works but i need to pause the counter when i press the left key, and i need to reenable it again when i press the right key, for this i currently use a case:

```
 document.onkeydown = function() {
  switch (window.event.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        myVid.muted=true;
        var div_by = 2445675675457,
        speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
        $display = $('.count'),
        run_count = 1,
        int_speed = 200;

          break;
      case 38:
        myVideo1.play(); 
        myVideo2.play();
        countUp(9999999999999);
          break;
      case 39:
        myVid.muted=false;
        var div_by = 2445675675457,
        speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
        $display = $('.count'),
        run_count = 1,
        int_speed = 9999999999999;
          break;
      case 40:
        myVideo1.pause();
        myVideo2.pause();  
          break;
  }
```

How can i achieve this

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with what you have?

Comment: It currently doesn't work. it's not stopping when i press left. Im kinda new to javascript, or coding in general.

Comment: In general try reduce your problem to it's simplest when posting here. Give as much useful information as you can and as little irrelevant information as you can. It's best to make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem if at all possible for html/css/javascript problems. I very often find when simplifying the problem for a jsfiddle that I discover what my problem was!

Comment: Oke i reduced the code to its minimum. http://jsfiddle.net/jHd6Q/

What i need the code to do is start the counter to count when i press the right key, and pause the counter to stop when i press the left key.

I tried some sollutions i came up my self, but all of those failed.

Comment: Perfectly done thanks. Don't forget to include any libraries (like jquery). You can select it on the left hand side from the handy dropdown menu. Anyway I hope my answer makes some sense of it for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very quick solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/vdgWs/

```
var isPaused = false;

function countUp(count)
{
  var div_by = 100,
  speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
  $display = $('#count'),
  run_count = 1,
  int_speed = 24;

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if(isPaused)
        return;
    if(run_count < div_by){
      $display.text(speed * run_count);
      run_count++;
    } else if(parseInt($display.text()) < count) {
      var curr_count = parseInt($display.text()) + 1;
      $display.text(curr_count);
    } else {
      clearInterval(int);
    }
    }, int_speed);
}

document.onkeydown = function() {
  switch (window.event.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        isPaused = true;
          break;
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function() {
  switch (window.event.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        isPaused=false;
          break;
  }
}
```

I didn't look too deeply into all your variables so I'm not sure what else can be cut out but here's a solution.

The problem is your keydown was being hit, but it had no effect on the countUp function running at the intervals as it was only affecting local variables, and the countUp was only using local variables..

I added a bool which is set on keydown and unset on keyup, and checked for the value of this bool when running the interval.

Also, I changed your count element to an ID instead of a class. Use IDs when there will only be one of this item, class for if there's many.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with it :)